# How to get all file attributes including author, title, mp3 tags, etc, in terminal

Tags: unix

How to get all the attributes in mp3 file including author, title, mp3 tags, etc, in terminal

Answer (score 3):

I use the `mp3info` command. On Ubuntu, install by `sudo apt-get install mp3info`. Home page: http://www.ibiblio.org/mp3info/

Comment: ya can i get the information of the remote mp3 file

Comment: You first have to download the file (use wget, for instance)

Comment: or ssh, if you can login to the remote system: `ssh -c 'mp3info /path/to/foo.mp3' user@host` ... naturally the remote system will need a copy of the *mp3info* program.

Answer (score 1):

There are several tools to do this, e.g. [id3ed](http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/HOWTO/MP3-HOWTO-13.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use id3info that comes with libid3.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the mp3-specific tools mentioned elsewhere are good options.  However, I'd like to suggest [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/#supported), which will handle all sorts of file types.  Very detailed, and it supports printf-style format strings, which are always handy when needing exact output formats for scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [**eyeD3**](http://freshmeat.net/projects/eyed3/)

> eyeD3 is a Python program and module that provides the ability to read and write ID3 tags (v1.x and v2.3/v2.4). It also decodes MP3 headers (bit rate, sample frequency, play time, etc.).